# How can I send a purchase e-mail to clients of a specific group? prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am using prestashop 1.6.
In the folder classes I modified the file Paymentmodule.php commenting this lines out

```
//  if (Validate::isEmail($this->context->customer->email)) {
                   //     Mail::Send(
                   //         (int)$order->id_lang,
                   //         'order_conf',
                    //        Mail::l('Order confirmation', (int)$order->id_lang),
                  //          $data,
                   //         $this->context->customer->email,
                   //         $this->context->customer->firstname.' '.$this->context->customer->lastname,
                    //        null,
                    //        null,
                    //        $file_attachement,
                   //         null, _PS_MAIL_DIR_, false, (int)$order->id_shop
                  //      );
                  //  }
```

so prestashop doesn’t send to registered costumers an order confirmation e-mail after every purchase they make.
Is there a way to send this mail, which is called order_conf, just to a group of clients? Maybe writing some code in paymentmodule.php or maybe with a module?

What I am looking for is the simplest way to send a confirmation mail to clients of a specific group after they purchase a product. Doesn't need to be order_conf.
Any ideas?
thanks for your time
bye

Comment: You want to send mail to clients of a specific group. Does that group needs to be default for those all customers which lies in that group ?

Answer (score 0):

**Condition 1**:

If you want to send mails to clients of specific group and that specific group is the default group of the clients to whom you want to send mails.

```
/** Here assuming you want to send mails to client of group "group 1" **/
$default_group = $this->context->customer->id_default_group;
$groups = Group::searchByName("group 1");
if($default_group == $groups['id_group']) {
    // Send mail code
}
```

**Condition 2**:

If you want to send mails to clients of specific group and that specific group is not the default group of the clients to whom you want to send mails.

```
/** Here assuming you want to send mails to client of group "group 2" no matter what is default group of client. **/
$groups=$this->context->customer->getGroups();
$mail_group=Group::searchByName("group 2");
foreach ($groups as $key=>$group){
    if($group=$mail_group['id_group']){
        //send mail code
    }
}
```

Comment: hi and thanks,
My condition is the second. Do I have to add these lines of code to Paymentmodule.php? Also: should "group 2"  become "my group name"? and should 'id_group'  change or not?

Comment: Yes you have to add these lines in your code. You can enclose the default email code between this code OR you can add this code and send another mail of your choice of template to clients. I have used "group 2" as it is impossible to remember the id of group. For example: you have group "private clients" and have 10 members in it. So you can write this string in place of group 2 and code will compare the id of "private group" with all groups of any particular client and if that client is in 10 members then it will enter into if condition

Comment: If it solved your problem up vote and mark this answer as approved. Thanks

Comment: I wrote an answer to my question asking you something if you read it and then tell me what you think that would be really great thanks

Answer (score 0):

So in place of “group 2” I put the name of the group which for me is “Grossisti” and in place of ‘id_group’ I put the id of the group which is ‘6’ (which I found in prestashop backoffice in the same line where there is the name of the group).
So in this way I am sending a mail after each purchase to all people in group Grossisti. Is it all correct?

```
$groups=$this->context->customer->getGroups();
$mail_group=Group::searchByName("Grossisti");
foreach ($groups as $key=>$group){
    if($group=$mail_group['6']){
        //send mail code
    }
}
```

If I want to send in the mail just some text like “the order has been placed”, how do I do that?

Ps: sorry if I should comment instead of answer but I needed for the formatting of the code.

Comment: You dont have to replace id_group. Leave the code as it is and replace group 2 with "Grossisti"

Comment: i uploaded the file with new code but nothing appens: the mail it's not being sent to the clients of the grossisti's group . what should I do next?

Comment: Then there must be some issue in your mail code. The code I shared is correct you can check by printing text in it.

Comment: i can write those lines of code wherever i want in paymentmodule.php, right?

Comment: Yes but inside any function otherwise it will throw an error. If this code helps up vote an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: can I send you the file and you write in it the lines of code where they need to be written? and then i'll shere here the solution if it worked for me